# Number sequence - differences don't converge

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm having problems with a particular number sequence:

```
175, 94, 188, 124, 376, 327, 1308, ...
```

I've tried working out the differences and have came up with this but I can't get anywhere from it.

```
175 94 188 124 376 327 1308
 -81 94 -64 252 -49 981 
  175 -158 316 -301 1030
   -333 474 -617 1331
    807 -1091 1948 
     -1898 3039
        4937
```

If someone can point me in the right direction of how to go about solving it.

Comment: And, do you know this one?
$$1,11,21,1211,111221,312211,13112221,...$$

Comment: @Berci: Look and tell? ${}$

Comment: @Berci: 1113213211, the point of asking me that was?

Comment: Sorry, didn't get your problem. Where is it from?

Comment: @Berci: Where is my question from you mean? I am taking the ipat test soon and I am working through various sequence examples for practise.

Comment: For a start look at the ratio of consecutive terms.

Comment: Can you give me any more info, still not sure

Comment: Colin, did you try what marty suggested? Did you, for example, divide 188 by 94? 376 by 124? 1308 by 327? Also, in the 2nd line of your triangle, look at the 1st, 3rd, and 5th entries --- do they look familiar?

Comment: I think the OP should give the method by which the sequence is generated. Otherwise as usual anything goes in extending it.